# Is there an equivalent function for x2fx in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Does numpy contain a function which is equivalent or similar to  [x2fx()](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/stats/x2fx.html) in Matlab? If not, has anyone a suggestion how this function could be efficiently emulated using functions provided by numpy?

Comment: Using statsmodels seems to be a more general solution. However, I had problems installing statsmodels on OS X Yosemite. Hence, a resorted to reimplementing a subset of the functionality x2fx() which fits my needs.

Answer (score 3):

This would be an efficient option in NumPy:

```
from itertools import combinations as comb

import numpy as np

def x2fx(x, model='linear'):
    linear = np.c_[np.ones(x.shape[0]), x]
    if model == 'linear':
        return linear
    if model == 'purequadratic':
        return np.c_[linear, x**2]
    interaction = np.hstack([x[:,i]*x[:,j] for i, j in
                                 comb(range(x.shape[1]), 2)]).T
    if model == 'interaction':
        return np.c_[linear, interaction]
    if model == 'quadratic':
        return np.c_[linear, interaction, x**2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Statsmodels is what you are looking for
An Example:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

model = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + log(x2)', data=your_dataframe)
design_matrix = model.exog
```

Look at the documentation of statsmodels for further information
It can both fit the model directly without generating the design matrix (implicitly) or explicitly genrate the design matrix as in the example.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/